# AngularFire 5 with Angular 9

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have an Angular project that uses Firebase and AngularFire. I recently upgraded to Angular v9 and just noticed that the `valueChanges` method is no longer working as expected. When a value changes in my database, it used to automatically return the new value, but not it is returning the old value, so the page has to refresh in order to get the new data.

I'm wondering if AngularFire v5 is not compatible with Angular v9? After some research, it appears AngularFire v6 is intended to work with Angular v9, but it hasn't been released yet and I can't find anything that says AngularFire v5 won't work with Angular 9.

I'd prefer not to use something that is still a release candidate, so I'm wondering if that's my only option.

Answer (score 0):

This basically answers my question. Sounds like AngularFire v5 and Angular 9 are not compatible, but AngularFire v6 will be available soon:
https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2267